# About monitor iphone application internet (http) traffic

Tags: ios, http

I hope someone here had the question. I want to monitor one of iphone's application' internet (http) traffic, I know the application sends out http request but I can't monitoring them, so now what tool I should use?

I tried fiddler but it seems the I can only get the first few request, I lose the traffic right after I logged in within that application.

So I can use fiddler to monitor iphone's browser traffice without any issue, but for applications I can't.

Answer (score 2):

Try [Charles HTTP proxy debugger](http://www.charlesproxy.com/). There's even a [section](http://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/faqs/) in the help for iOS applications.

If you want to debug HTTPS traffic as well you'll need to right click on the requests in the list and select `SSL proxying` and then re-attempt the request.

Comment: thanks. However I installed the certification on my ios 5, but still can't get any traffic within the application. Do I need to install the certification on my own computer where Charles is installed?

Comment: You need to also do [this](http://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/faqs/#qa_187) to make sure your requests are going though Charles. You don't need to install that certificate on your computer. Before trying the application, first try with mobile safari with google or something :)

Comment: Just want to specify that this is a native application not web application. but It indeed sent http/https request to its server.

Comment: The safari browser works just like when I use fiddler, all the traffic is fine. I installed the certification on my ios in case the application uses any SSL , but I didn't see any traffic after I started using the application. Now I notice one note says SSL Proxying not enabled for this host: enable in Proxy Settings, SSL locations. not sure how this is working.

Comment: Yeah, but its easy to test that Charles is picking up the traffic using Safari, once you've done that you can try with the app. Once you see any traffic from the device in Charles you're 95% there!

Comment: @user3306308 ah great. Can you see any request with the host name you are connecting to in Charles?

Comment: +1 for suggesting Charles. Yes, it allows you to see absolutely all HTTP traffic coming in and out of your app: headers, requests, responses etc. I use it almost every day for web-services-integration debugging in iOS apps.

Comment: I played around Charles. However since I couldn't get deeper I ended up using tcpdump (I had to use my android phone since I don't have a MAC computer). and then copy the result to wiredshark to see TCP transmissions. The whole process is a pain since I don't know too much about linux commands. Anyway I hope there is a easy way via either fiddler or Charles to monitor all TCP traffic rather use any of those command line tools.